# Why does running bash scripts containing Java commands give me "missing classes" error?

Tags: java, scripts

A have few .sh files that I want to run.

I was a regular Windows user, so i haven't much of idea about it. I had .bat files, which were doing proper work for me. But when I switched to Ubuntu it's showing an error:

```
proton@proton-5750:~/Desktop/nand to tetris$ ./HardwareSimulator.sh
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HardwareSimulatorMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HardwareSimulatorMain
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: HardwareSimulatorMain. Program will exit.
proton@proton-5750:~/Desktop/nand to tetris$ ./HardwareSimulator.sh
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HardwareSimulatorMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HardwareSimulatorMain
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: HardwareSimulatorMain. Program will exit.
```

I don't why these Java errors are happening in Ubuntu...

Guys give me solution, thanks in advance.....

Comment: i've tried sh filename.sh and bash filename.sh, still the problem n error is same....

Comment: The problem is **not** the sh file, but that it includes Java commands.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely thing is that the shell script (for starting a Java program) has been ported from Windows but the construction of the classpath is still using semicolons ; on Linux, the PATH separator is the colon. Try replacing semicolons in the -cp parameter with colons. Or alternately, since the default Java install in Ubuntu is Java 6, the wildcard form for the -cp parameter will work - pass the folder containing the jar files, with a /* at the end. You'll have to enclose that in single quotes so that the shell doesn't expand it.

Answer (score 0):

From this link:

[3 ways to resolve ***NoClassDefFoundError*** in Java](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html)

***1***
Class is not available in [Java Classpath ( *How to Set Classpath for Java on Windows Unix and Linux* ).](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-classpath-work-in-java.html)
***2***
You might be running your program using jar command and class was not defined in manifest file's ClassPath attribute.
***3***
Any startup script is overriding Classpath environment variable.